# Finding relative price strength as defined in CANSLIM stock picking methodology

Tags: equities, market-data, price

I am wondering if there is any website that provides **relative price strength** as is defined in CAN SLIM stock picking methodology.
For the CAN SLIM difinition I am looking at this article:

http://www.investopedia.com/university/stockpicking/stockpicking7.asp

I searched the Internet and found a suggestion to use *barchart* website: http://www.barchart.com/technicals/stocks/AMD

It has a *Relative Strength* column, but its definition is something different.

I appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Probably a better question for money.stackexchange. IBD publishes data feeds and you can get it on the IBD website.

Comment: Can you edit your question posting an academic (more reliable) reference about building this indicator up? If there is not that kind of reference, I think the question is off-topic and, as posted by @NathanS., more suitable money.SE.